# Why is my Wifi i NetworkManager always saying 'Device not ready'?

Tags: networking, wireless

Every time I click on a WiFi name to connect to it the NetworkManager blinks while doing the "connecting" animation and comes back with an empty list of Access Points, just saying "Device not ready" under the WiFi Networks label.

Sometimes right after starting up the computer the behaviour is the same.

Doing `service NetworkManager restart` once or several times may fix it until it happens again.

This is the output for `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3`:

```
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 7260 [8086:08b1] (rev 73)
Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-AC 7260 [8086:4070]
Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
Kernel modules: iwlwifi
```

This is my output for `dmesg | grep iwl`:

```
[    4.232474] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: loaded firmware version 17.352738.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[    4.273915] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 7260, REV=0x144
[    4.275958] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Enabled
[    4.276207] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Enabled
[    4.501098] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-mvm-rs'
[    6.578804] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Enabled
[    6.579039] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Enabled
[    6.794808] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Enabled
[    6.795043] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Enabled
[   21.063014] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Enabled
[   21.063243] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Enabled
[   21.275815] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Enabled
[   21.276046] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Enabled
[   47.508071] WARNING: CPU: 0 PID: 6351 at /build/linux-ItCWVk/linux-4.8.0/drivers/net/wireless/intel/iwlwifi/mvm/time-event.c:507 iwl_mvm_time_event_send_add+0x1c6/0x200 [iwlmvm]
[   47.508071] Modules linked in: appletalk ipx p8023 p8022 psnap llc rfcomm cmac bnep binfmt_misc arc4 uvcvideo videobuf2_vmalloc videobuf2_memops videobuf2_v4l2 videobuf2_core videodev intel_rapl x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp coretemp media kvm_intel kvm iwlmvm btusb btrtl btbcm irqbypass crct10dif_pclmul mac80211 crc32_pclmul btintel ghash_clmulni_intel bluetooth aesni_intel snd_hda_codec_hdmi aes_x86_64 lrw snd_hda_codec_via glue_helper snd_hda_codec_generic ablk_helper cryptd intel_cstate snd_hda_intel intel_rapl_perf snd_hda_codec iwlwifi snd_hda_core snd_hwdep input_leds snd_pcm joydev snd_seq_midi serio_raw snd_seq_midi_event snd_rawmidi cfg80211 rtsx_pci_ms snd_seq memstick snd_seq_device snd_timer lpc_ich snd mei_me mei soundcore shpchp ie31200_edac tpm_infineon mac_hid edac_core parport_pc
[   47.508134]  [<ffffffffc0c509b6>] iwl_mvm_time_event_send_add+0x1c6/0x200 [iwlmvm]
[   47.508139]  [<ffffffffc0c51628>] iwl_mvm_protect_session+0x228/0x290 [iwlmvm]
[   47.508143]  [<ffffffffc0c37693>] ? iwl_mvm_ref_sync+0x33/0x140 [iwlmvm]
[   47.508167]  [<ffffffffc0c37bda>] iwl_mvm_mac_mgd_prepare_tx+0x5a/0xa0 [iwlmvm]
[   70.894127] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Enabled
[   70.894355] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Enabled
[   71.112554] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Enabled
[   71.112796] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Enabled
[   71.672837] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Enabled
[   71.673066] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Enabled
[   71.896882] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Enabled
[   71.897111] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Enabled
[   72.763197] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Enabled
[   72.763426] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Enabled
[   72.978939] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Enabled
[   72.979166] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Enabled
[  103.143992] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Enabled
[  103.144221] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Enabled
[  103.366001] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Enabled
[  103.366258] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Enabled
[  111.614759] WARNING: CPU: 1 PID: 13477 at /build/linux-ItCWVk/linux-4.8.0/drivers/net/wireless/intel/iwlwifi/mvm/time-event.c:507 iwl_mvm_time_event_send_add+0x1c6/0x200 [iwlmvm]
[  111.614760] Modules linked in: appletalk ipx p8023 p8022 psnap llc rfcomm cmac bnep binfmt_misc arc4 uvcvideo videobuf2_vmalloc videobuf2_memops videobuf2_v4l2 videobuf2_core videodev intel_rapl x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp coretemp media kvm_intel kvm iwlmvm btusb btrtl btbcm irqbypass crct10dif_pclmul mac80211 crc32_pclmul btintel ghash_clmulni_intel bluetooth aesni_intel snd_hda_codec_hdmi aes_x86_64 lrw snd_hda_codec_via glue_helper snd_hda_codec_generic ablk_helper cryptd intel_cstate snd_hda_intel intel_rapl_perf snd_hda_codec iwlwifi snd_hda_core snd_hwdep input_leds snd_pcm joydev snd_seq_midi serio_raw snd_seq_midi_event snd_rawmidi cfg80211 rtsx_pci_ms snd_seq memstick snd_seq_device snd_timer lpc_ich snd mei_me mei soundcore shpchp ie31200_edac tpm_infineon mac_hid edac_core parport_pc
[  111.614841]  [<ffffffffc0c509b6>] iwl_mvm_time_event_send_add+0x1c6/0x200 [iwlmvm]
[  111.614848]  [<ffffffffc0c51628>] iwl_mvm_protect_session+0x228/0x290 [iwlmvm]
[  111.614853]  [<ffffffffc0c37693>] ? iwl_mvm_ref_sync+0x33/0x140 [iwlmvm]
[  111.614880]  [<ffffffffc0c37bda>] iwl_mvm_mac_mgd_prepare_tx+0x5a/0xa0 [iwlmvm]
[  114.295731] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Enabled
[  114.295959] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Enabled
[  114.528393] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Enabled
[  114.528622] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Enabled
[  115.439801] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Enabled
[  115.440031] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Enabled
[  115.645633] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Enabled
[  115.645862] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Enabled
[  141.467685] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Enabled
[  141.467916] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Enabled
[  141.702220] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Enabled
[  141.702450] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Enabled
[  157.079970] WARNING: CPU: 1 PID: 20568 at /build/linux-ItCWVk/linux-4.8.0/drivers/net/wireless/intel/iwlwifi/mvm/time-event.c:507 iwl_mvm_time_event_send_add+0x1c6/0x200 [iwlmvm]
[  157.079971] Modules linked in: ccm appletalk ipx p8023 p8022 psnap llc rfcomm cmac bnep binfmt_misc arc4 uvcvideo videobuf2_vmalloc videobuf2_memops videobuf2_v4l2 videobuf2_core videodev intel_rapl x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp coretemp media kvm_intel kvm iwlmvm btusb btrtl btbcm irqbypass crct10dif_pclmul mac80211 crc32_pclmul btintel ghash_clmulni_intel bluetooth aesni_intel snd_hda_codec_hdmi aes_x86_64 lrw snd_hda_codec_via glue_helper snd_hda_codec_generic ablk_helper cryptd intel_cstate snd_hda_intel intel_rapl_perf snd_hda_codec iwlwifi snd_hda_core snd_hwdep input_leds snd_pcm joydev snd_seq_midi serio_raw snd_seq_midi_event snd_rawmidi cfg80211 rtsx_pci_ms snd_seq memstick snd_seq_device snd_timer lpc_ich snd mei_me mei soundcore shpchp ie31200_edac tpm_infineon mac_hid edac_core
[  157.080036]  [<ffffffffc0c509b6>] iwl_mvm_time_event_send_add+0x1c6/0x200 [iwlmvm]
[  157.080041]  [<ffffffffc0c51628>] iwl_mvm_protect_session+0x228/0x290 [iwlmvm]
[  157.080045]  [<ffffffffc0c37693>] ? iwl_mvm_ref_sync+0x33/0x140 [iwlmvm]
[  157.080069]  [<ffffffffc0c37bda>] iwl_mvm_mac_mgd_prepare_tx+0x5a/0xa0 [iwlmvm]
[  166.306065] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Enabled
[  166.306295] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Enabled
[  166.527382] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Enabled
[  166.527612] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Enabled
[  183.303615] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Enabled
[  183.303844] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Enabled
[  183.522579] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Enabled
[  183.522807] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Enabled
[  187.482803] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Enabled
[  187.483032] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Enabled
[  187.715754] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Enabled
[  187.715982] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Enabled
[ 1773.397809] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Enabled
[ 1773.398036] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Enabled
[ 1773.628642] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Enabled
[ 1773.628871] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Enabled
[ 1773.660537] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Enabled
[ 1773.660764] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Enabled
[ 1773.871990] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Enabled
[ 1773.872223] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Enabled
[ 2223.368105] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Enabled
[ 2223.368333] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Enabled
[ 2223.588761] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Enabled
[ 2223.588990] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Enabled
[ 2223.620129] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Enabled
[ 2223.620356] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Enabled
[ 2223.837057] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Enabled
[ 2223.837284] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Enabled
[ 6878.816007] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Enabled
[ 6878.816234] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Enabled
[ 6879.039483] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Enabled
[ 6879.039712] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Enabled
[ 6879.067990] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Enabled
[ 6879.068218] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Enabled
[ 6879.292200] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Enabled
[ 6879.292428] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Enabled
[27019.031717] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Enabled
[27019.031944] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Enabled
[27019.262262] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Enabled
[27019.262506] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Enabled
[27084.806832] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Enabled
[27084.807081] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Enabled
[27085.039018] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Enabled
[27085.039245] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Enabled
[42434.973973] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Enabled
[42434.974251] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Enabled
[42435.188297] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Enabled
[42435.188524] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Enabled
[42435.328480] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Enabled
[42435.328709] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Enabled
[42435.548942] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Enabled
[42435.549169] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Enabled
[43949.776581] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Enabled
[43949.776904] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Enabled
[43950.002266] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Enabled
[43950.002504] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Enabled
[43953.058747] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Enabled
[43953.059010] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Enabled
[43953.286370] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Enabled
[43953.286597] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Enabled
```

Output for `rfkill`:

```
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
6: hci0: Bluetooth
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3` terminal command.

Comment: What is the Ubuntu version? Please add output of `dmesg | grep iwl`.

Comment: Just added the output for that. I have ubuntu 16.10 but this has been happing in previous versions too

Comment: Please post the output of `rfkill list`.

Comment: Okay, added the rfkill list

Comment: It looks OK. There is a kernel problem. Report it as a bug. I am using another revision of 7260 with no problems.